# Are these both the probability of collision in birthday attack?

Tags: birthday-attack, collision-attack

About birthday attack,
book *Cryptography Engineering* says:

> In general, if an element can take on N different values, then you can
> expect the first collision after choosing about $\sqrt{N}$ random
> elements. We're leaving out the exact details here, but $\sqrt{N}$ is
> fairly close. For the birthday paradox, we have N = 365 and $\sqrt{N} \approx   19$. The number of people required before the chance of a
> duplicate birthday exceeds 50% is in fact 23, but $\sqrt{N}$ is close
> enough for our purposes and is the approximation that cryptographers
> often use.
>
> One way of looking at this is that if you choose $k$ elements, then
> there are $k(k - 1)/2$ pairs of elements, each of which has a $1/N$
> chance of being a pair of equal values. **So the chance of finding a
> collision is close to $k(k - 1)/2N$.** When $k = \sqrt{N}$, this chance
> is close to 50 % .

and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack) says:

> As an example, consider the scenario in which a teacher with a class of 30 students (n = 30) asks for everybody's birthday (for simplicity, ignore leap years) to determine whether any two students have the same birthday (corresponding to a hash collision as described further). Intuitively, this chance may seem small. Counter-intuitively, **the probability that at least one student has the same birthday as any other student on any day is around 70% (for n = 30), from the formula ${\displaystyle 1-{\frac {365!}{(365-n)!\cdot 365^{n}}}}$.**

which can be rephrased in terms of the language in *Cryptography Engineering*:

$$1 - \frac{N!}{(N-k)! * N^k}$$

Is it supposed to equal to the following from *Cryptography Engineering*:

$$ (k(k-1))/(2N) $$

Why?

Comment: That is about approximation that you did not notice on Wikipedia page. and possible dupes are [What are the odds of collisions for a hash function with 256-bit output?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/39641/18298) and [Birthday Attack Probability of Collision in Introduction to Modern Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/72791/18298) and [On a lower bound for the birthday problem](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/64584/18298) and [What is the error in this collision probability approximation?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/66328/18298) and some other not listed...

Comment: Wiki page: [Birthday problem - Approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Approximations)

Comment: Thanks. @kelalaka. I don't find (k(k−1))/(2N) in the links. Do I miss it?

Comment: See `This is fine for low ` in the first link 101 answer...

Comment: @kelalaka Thanks. The book in my post seems to explain  (k(k−1))/(2N) in a different way. Are the pairs each having two equal values disjoint events?

Comment: It first selects uniform random $k$ values then forms the pair where each has $1/N$ chance of collision....

Comment: A derivation of the approximation is in my [_Birthday problem for cryptographic hashing, 101_](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/39644/555). Beware that uses $(k,n)$ where the present question uses $(N,k)$.

Comment: @fgrieu  Thanks. I still have the same question. The book in my post seems to explain (k(k−1))/(2N) in a different way from your answer. How shall I understand it from 1/N for each pair? Are the pairs each having two equal values disjoint events? Which part in its derivation is approximation?

Answer (score 2):

The question asks how we go from $\displaystyle p=1 - \frac{N!}{(N-k)!\,N^k}$  for the probability of collision of $k$ uniformly random values among $N$, to the approximation $\displaystyle p\approx\frac{k(k-1)}{2N}$ (which assumes $k$ is small compared to $\sqrt N$ ).

First we get back to $\displaystyle1-p=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}{\left(1-\frac j N\right)}$, which is how $p$ was determined in the first place. Then we take the logarithm on both sides and use that $u>0,v>0\implies\ln(u\,v)=\ln(u)+\ln(v)$ to get
$$\displaystyle\ln(1-p)=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}{\ln\left(1-\frac j N\right)}$$

For small $|x|$, it hold $\ln(1+x)\approx x$. Applying this to $x=p$ on the left side and $\displaystyle x=\frac j N$ on the right side, we get $\displaystyle p\approx\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac j N$. We rewrite this as $\displaystyle p\approx\frac 1 N\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}j$.

Now we use that the sum of non-negative integers less than $k$ is $\displaystyle\frac{k\,(k-1)}2$ and get the desired $\displaystyle p\approx\frac{k(k-1)}{2N}$.

Without proof: this approximation of $p$ is always by excess. It's off by less than $+28\%$ when $k\le\sqrt N$, less than $+14\%$ when $k\le\sqrt{2N}$, less than $+7\%$ when $k\le2\sqrt N$.

---

Most of the error is from the approximation $\ln(1-p)\approx-p$. A much better approximation is:
$$p\approx1-e^{-\frac{k(k-1)}{2N}}$$
which assumes only $k\ll N$ rather than $k\ll\sqrt N$. However beware that this alternate formula is numerically instable for small $p$.

---

In comment it's additionally asked

> How shall I understand (this formula) from $1/N$ for each pair? Are the pairs each having two equal values disjoint events? Which part in its derivation is approximation?

One easy way to derive the probability $p$ that there is a collision among $k$ uniform values among $N$ (for $0\le k\le N$) is as the complement of the probability that there is not collision.

For a fixed $N$, define $q_k$ as the probability that there is no collision after $k$ values. Obviously $q_0=q_1=1$. And for $k\ge2$, $q_k$ is the probability that there was no collision among the first $k-1$ values (that is, $q_{k-1}$), time the probability that there is no collision between the $k-1$ previous values and the last drawn one, which is $\displaystyle\frac{N-k}N$ (justification there a exactly $N-k$ values among $N$ that do not leak to collision for the last value drawn).

It follows $\displaystyle q_k=q_{k-1}\left(1-\frac k N\right)$, thus $\displaystyle q_k=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}{\left(1-\frac j N\right)}$, thus $$p=1-\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}{\left(1-\frac j N\right)}=1-\frac{N!}{(N-k)!\,N^k}$$

This is exact. See first two sections of this answer for the derivation of approximations.

---

One source justified the approximation as:

> One way of looking at this is that if you choose $k$ elements, then there are $k(k−1)/2$ pairs of elements, each of which has a $1/N$ chance of being a pair of equal values.

This hand-waving argument does not yield a mathematically exact derivation of $\displaystyle p=\frac{k(k-1)}{2N}$, since the events are not disjoint. As long as $p$ is small, we can get away with it, but that gets grossly wrong when $k>\sqrt{2N}$.

> When $k = \sqrt{N}$, this chance is close to 50%.

That's true if 39.3% is close to 50%.

Comment: Thanks. My comment at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/99160/are-these-both-the-probability-of-collision-in-birthday-attack/99176#comment214408_99160 asked for different questions

Comment: If you take a look at the first quote in my post, the book doesn't derive the probability the way your added to your reply

Comment: "since the events are not independent." Additivity of probabilities of several events depends on the events being disjoint not independent

Comment: The percentages need links...

Comment: @kelalaka: my evidence for +28% is only numerical (hence the _without proof_): I plotted $\frac{\left(1-\frac{{k^2}!}{(k^2-k)!\,k^{2k}}\right)\,2k^2}{k(k-1)}-1$; same for +14% +7%.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Does your "First we get back to ... get the desired p≈k(k−1)/2N" justify (k(k−1))/(2N) as a reasonable approximation? (2) Does "This hand-waving argument does not yield a mathematically exact derivation of p=k(k−1)/2N, since the events are not disjoint. As long as p is small, we can get away with it, but that gets grossly wrong when k>sqrt(2N). When k=sqrt(N), this chance is close to 50%. That's true if 39.3% is close to 50%" mean that k(k−1)/2N is a bad approximation? (3) if you don't mean contradiction in (1) (2), could you explain, edit, or paraphrase what you actually mean?

Comment: (1) More precisely, it implies $k(k−1)/(2N)$ is a valid approximation _for $k$ or $p$ lower than some threshold._ (2) It means that $k(k−1)/(2N)$ is poorly justified by the argument given, comes without a statement of when it applies, and is a terrible approximation for $k$ above some thresold. As explained, it's already significantly off (by +24%) when applied to $k=\sqrt N$ and $N$ of cryptographic interest. (3) There's no contradiction.